# How do i add faces back into my model

Tags: mesh, faces, wireframe

I accidentally deleted all of the faces at some point and i can't bring them back, it looks like wire-frame[image] mode but is not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first place I'd check would be your Object Properties -> Viewport Display options. See if Display As is set to Wire. If so, set it to Textured or Solid.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! this was my problem

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried selecting all and pressing F to fill? It should do the trick but you'll probably have to go back into wireframe and manually delete any faces filled inside the mesh.

Comment: You shouldn't have to. Just press A to select all (unless you reconfigured the shortcuts) then F to fill in faces. If that doesn't work I would check the viewport display as Electric Wizard suggested, you might be in a sort of wireframe mode.